# Configurar Wordpress en español, problemas

Tags: wordpress, virtualbox, idioma

tengo un problema para cambiar Wordpress en mi máquina virtual de **Ubuntu 18.04** al español.

Simplemente me sale todo en inglés, sin la posibilidad de cambiarlo a español,solo me deja la posibilidad de ponerlo en "English (United states)" en los ajustes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He pensado que a lo mejor editando el archivo */var/www/html/wp-config.php* me saldría, pero buscando en otros blogs, he intentado configurarlo de tal manera:
[image: ![]

Y aún así no me ha dejado cambiarlo. En otras partes me decía de configurar el archivo en *wp-content/languages* pero ese archivo no me sale, en su caso me sale *wp-content/.languages.swp*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Introduzco esa ruta para ver qué contiene e intentar editar algo para cambiar el idioma y solo me sale esto como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor alguien que me de una solución factible?
Por si acaso, mi versión de Wordpress es la **Versión 5.3**

Answer (score 1):

primero tienes que instalar el idioma al que deseas cambiar
1.- Accede al dashboard, y asegúrate en Actualizaciones que ya estás usando WordPress 4.1.0.
2.- Ve a Ajustes, Generales.
3.- Al final de la pantalla localiza Idioma del sitio.
4.- Despliega el selector y localiza el idioma deseado.
5.- Haz clic en Guardar cambios.
Automáticamente se instalará el nuevo idioma (si no estaba instalado) y se activará por defecto
otra opcion seria descargar el paquete de idiomas desde la pagina oficial y instalarla en tu proyecto.

Comment: Me ha salido el desplegable de "Español" y tengo la versión 5.3, pero aún clickando en el idioma español y guardando los cambios, no me cambia el idioma de la página ni de los proyectos.

Comment: en la opción de cambiar hay dos opciones una para la vista y otra que es para la administración si quieres ambas vistas en español tendrías que hacer los dos cambios. o en todo caso descargar el proyecto WordPress en español y volverlo a instalar saludos.